How do I use partial specializations as template template parameters?
I have a class template taking a template template parameter
template<template<class> typename T>
struct S {};

and a class template taking 2 template parameters
template<size_t i, typename T>
struct A {};

Is there any way to instantiate S with a partial specialization of A over the i parameter, so that I can write the following?
S<A< /*someNumber*/ >> someStruct;


I can create an alias template
template<typename T>
using Inner = A<5, T>;

and instantiate S with it
S<Inner> SInner;

But this only works for the fixed value of 5, because alias templates can't be partially specialized. Is there maybe some way to make Inner a template?

You might organize your code differently:
template <size_t i>
struct A_outer {
    template <typename T>
    struct A{};
};

S<A_outer<42>::A> s;

Demo

In case A is not modifiable for some reason, the member could just be an alias template https://godbolt.org/z/dhc83qfqe
